# Will a 200A panel serve my circuit needs?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I currently have a 125 amp panel that is full/maxed out.  I plan on adding the following loads, and need to know if a 200 amp panel upgrade will be enough, or if I need more (300? 400?).

Two EVSEs (EV charging gateways).

A 15.3 KW solar system (that needs an 80 amp breaker)

A hot tub

Replacing a gas water heater with an on demand water heater that needs three 40 amp breakers

An on-demand pool water heater that needs two 40 amp breakers

Comment: Replacing gas with on demand heaters is probably not the best of ideas.

Comment: Do you want the PowerWalls for backup or for peak shaving? If for backup, are you OK with having no hot water during power outages? Highly unlikely the PowerWall can run  one of those.

Comment: What are all the loads in your current panel (labeled photo would be a good start)? What size breakers do the hot tub and EV chargers require? Do you need to be able to use both chargers at once?

Comment: Yes, can you get us a photo of your existing panel (with labels), as well as photos of the nameplates (or at least the nameplate wattage/amperage rating, *not* the circuit breaker size!) for your range/cooking appliances and air conditioner?

Answer (score 1):

There is a formal procedure to figure this out, called a *Load Calculation*. Google can help you find some online calculators, or your electrician can do it for you. A load calculation adds up:

- Certain required circuits (e.g., kitchen receptacles)
- Built-in appliances such as oven, cooktop, dryer, etc.
- Water heater (which is where the on-demand comes in...)
- HVAC
- EV charging
- A general 3W per square foot catch-all for lighting and other stuff
- Any other known extras - e.g., hot tub

A lot of things are added "as is". Some things have adjustments - e.g., if you have air conditioning + resistance heating, only the larger one gets counted because they don't run at the same time.

But based on a lot of previous questions, I suspect that everything is great **except** the on demand water heaters. If they are all going at once that's 160A (5 * 40 *. 8).

Why do you want on demand water heaters? Tanked water heaters have far lower demand. If your existing heaters don't produce/store enough to get through peak times, get more and/or larger tanks.

---

Digging deeper, here are my rough theories on this type of stuff, which I think is relevant here.

There are, in my opinion, generally two reasons to head down the solar + Powerwall (or other battery backup, though the Tesla Powerwall is a very good, turnkey product) route.

- Resiliency during power outages.

For this purpose, solar + Powerwall is great. On-demand water heating? Not so great. Why? The heavy loads of on-demand water heating simply don't go well with the limits of battery backup. In particular, the demand level for on-demand water heating can easily be higher than what a battery system (or a typical generator, for that matter) can provide. On the other hand, a tank system (whether natural gas, traditional resistance electric or fuel pump) gives you a good reserve of water (30 or 40 gallons, can easily double with two tanks, larger tanks available, etc.) so that for a short outage (e.g., a day or less) with moderate usage you will hardly notice the problem. And if the outage is longer then with natural gas there is no problem at all (unless the gas is out too) and with electric and solar it may still be practical to heat water at least some of the time - possibly managing it manually to heat during peak solar time.

- Environmental/Carbon/etc.

Whatever you want to call it, this reason comes down to saving energy and producing energy in a better (not burning stuff) way. The key here is the solar panels - they help supplement utility power (possibly pumping power back into the grid) and provide power when the utility is out, both directly and via the battery backup. Based on this reason, you may logically want to get away from natural gas as well, based on the theory that utility power is gradually shifting to hydro, solar, wind, nuclear (yes, nuclear is good for the environment except for Chernobyl and Fukushima), etc. and away from gas and coal. But in this case you want to avoid peak power demands - if everyone has on-demand water heating and turns on the hot water faucet at the same time then the utility may turn on a natural gas peaker plant to compensate. And while you can argue that there is a slight efficiency advantage (and therefore environmental benefit) to on-demand water heating over tank heating - after all, you don't lose heat from water that is just sitting there all day - tanks are now extremely well insulated (so very little loss) and if you really want the heating to be *more* efficient you go for fuel pump water heaters, which are significantly more efficient than resistance heating (whether tank or tankless) and more efficient than natural gas (which otherwise can, depending on utility electricity source, be arguably more efficient than electric heating).

For some people there is a third reason to change - save money. Based on the overall question, I don't think that's the case here. 2 EV chargers? Hot tub? Heated pool? All fine things, and I won't argue with anyone who can afford them - nothing wrong with that. But I will add that while on-demand water heaters are typically quite a bit cheaper than fuel pump water heaters (which are still a new and complex technology compared to traditional water heaters or tankless), if money is an issue I would go with traditional tank, either natural gas or electric depending on (a) how concerned I am about burning natural gas and (b) local pricing (in some places electricity is a lot cheaper (some hydro or nuclear areas) than others. Tankless electric would still not be on the short list.

As far as space concerns, that *might* point to an advantage for traditional electric tank water heaters over all the other options. Gas requires exhaust venting. Fuel pump has other issues in terms of where the heat comes from to heat the water. Regular electric tank heaters (resistance heat) can be pretty much anywhere - big ones in the basement, small ones under the sink, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response :)  I forgot to add that I also want to add two Powerwalls for solar storage.  As for the water heaters, the on-demand ones take up much less space that I need for the powerwalls and other things.

Comment: I think it is a foolish move. EV charging, solar, powerwall all good. You can't spare a few square feet for tanks? The name of the game in electric is peak demand management. On demand electric water heating goes the wrong way.

Comment: Seems like someone wants to save some money with the solar and powerwalls.  Those on demand heaters would probably put any savings into the negative.

Comment: DV care to explain?

Comment: You can’t say “everything is great”. Have you done a load calculation for the OP’s house?

Comment: @nobody Can I say 100%: No. I based it on (a) current 125A full/maxed is *probably* more "full" than "maxed out in current carrying capacity" because it does not include EV chargers, pool heater, regular water heater (currently gas), so 125A is probably quite adequate right now (but not guaranteed - OP didn't tell us about the bitcoin mining room); and (b) solar relates to panel size but not utility capacity (generally, since it is going the other direction), EV can be managed (just because you have 2 EV that could charge at 40A each at the same time doesn't mean you have to configure to

Comment: allow that), hot tub isn't necessarily all that much - so it is not unreasonable that all that could be configured within the new 75A (plus probably some surplus from the old setup) - which leaves the on-demand as the **BIG** issue.

Comment: @nobody, "based on a lot of previous questions, I _suspect_ that everything is great except..." (emphasis added). Based on a lot of previous questions, OP probably _is_ using less power than what it says on the panel label. Also, Manasseh did say "suspect", i.e. it's a supposition, and educated best guess based on the information available and historical knowledge. He did _not_, by any means, categorically claim that OP doesn't need a service upgrade. He also lead into this with an explanation of the load calculation necessary to _confirm_ his _supposition_.

Comment: @FreeMan Correct. And I actually do suspect OP needs a service upgrade in order to handle EVs, hot tub, etc. My hunch is that 125A -> 200A will be enough to cover everything *except* on-demand electric water heating.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Based on the comments, additional research, and conversations with contractors, I am going with an electric heat pump water heater for both the house and the pool (just found out they make them for pools). This will make my whole house electric (already converted everything else, which is why my 125 amp panel is full).  According to the electrical engineer, the solar system will need two 40 amp breakers.  Plus, whatever the two heat pump water heaters need, plus a 50 amp for a hot tub, and whatever 2 EV chargers need.  With all that, would a 200 amp panel be sufficient?

Comment: My main concern is safety, quality, going green, and not necessarily cost (although I don’t want to waste money).

Comment: For safety and quality, anything done right (UL listed, installed properly, etc.) will do. For going green, heat pump water heater is **absolutely** the best choice because it uses less total energy than traditional tanked or tankless, including natural gas. As far as 200A panel, *probably* enough, but really need a load calc to figure out for sure. Remember the solar is "the other direction" so it in certain ways subtracts rather than adds. But it gets complicated because of Powerwall charging and other factors. Really need a local pro (knowing the local codes, among other things) to figure

Comment: it all out. But it sounds quite doable. If you can make it all work with one 200A panel you are definitely in better shape because 350/400 service is typically 2 separate 200A panels, which raises other complications (not insurmountable, but complicating) with respect to solar and battery.

Answer (score 1):

### Two EVs: you *must* understand Share2 technology.

Do not simply treat two EVs as two totally separate loads.   And remember that EV charging rates *are adjustable, automatically*.

Those so-called "chargers" are actually EVSE's.

This video does a great job covering EV charging basics but I recommend starting at 19:15 unless you want the basic basics covered. **And especially 28:15.  The upshot is you don't [need](https://youtu.be/Iyp_X3mwE1w?t=1718) nearly as much EV charging power as you think**.  60A or even 100A is deluxe... but a *very modest* 20A/240V* circuit will charge at almost 4000 watts, giving typically 120 miles of range in 10 hours. *Do you really need more?*

But let's say you listened to me (I say 20A*), and installed 20A* per EV (40A* total) and one day you're in a rush and *really, really* want to throw all 40A into one car.  *Whatever will you do?*   Unplug the other car (or be the only car) **And. It. Just. Happens.**

... Assuming you had the forethought to use Share2 equipped EVSEs and enabled this.

This is not your father's charging tech. Share2 EVSE's talk to each other, and agree to split the current allocation (which is decided by your electric service size). They have a max *per charger* (decided by the wire to each unit). The units talk to each other and coordinate. If one car is absent, the other car gets the full boat.

Some makers produce Share2 EVSEs, some make single EVSEs that charge 2 cars, **and every single Tesla wall unit has had this feature since at least 2018**.  (v2 and v3 units).

And if you *really want* two 40A* circuits for the two EVs, I say *Still* combine them using Share2 so that a larger EV can go to town at 60-80A* when it is charging solo.  Why not? Tesla gives it to you for free, for Pete's sake. (and you can charge non-Teslas on Tesla EVSEs, since the AC wiring *and signal* standards are identical, only the plug shape differs.

If you're wondering about the nuts and bolts under the hood that make this tech possible,
[watch this video for a deep dive into the tech.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMxB7zA-e4Y)

The takeaway is you don't need *that much* power for EV charging, and when you need to dedicate it all to one EV for some quicker charging, that's super easy if you use Share2 EVSE's.  Use this to make stuff fit on a service size if you need to.

---

* I'm giving the circuit size / size you would place in the NEC Load Calculation.  But NEC requires *actual* charging rate to be 80% of that.  Thus on a 20A circuit x 240V (nominally 4800W), we actually charge at 80% (3840W).

### A PowerWall is not an afterthought!

Really, your system needs to be designed around the PowerWall.  Because an unseen requirement of the PowerWall is a very big and particular automatic transfer switch to disconnect it from grid so it's possible to light up your house during a power outage.  These are the first stop past the electric meter, so doing this as an "oops" change will be costly and result in "total loss of control of aesthetics".

Fortunately, the Tesla Gateway is designed to accommodate NEC 2020 disconnect requirements, so you will not need an outside meter-main.  Any $30 unfused disconnect will suffice. (it's only switching a few milliamps, the main thing it must do is *be recognizable as a disconnect*.

And, these gateways only support 200A. So if you want 400A service (typically done with two 200A panels), either you'll need two of them, or have only one panel on battery backup. Which doesn't sound like your style.

So no.  The Powerwalls (or rather the Gateways) need *to define* your electrical system.

### On-demand hot water *is perfectly fine*.

It's a perfectly great way to heat water, and more economical for several reasons.

First, you're only heating it *when you actually need it*, not keeping a kettle warm 24x7, which while fans will protest adds up to very little, it does add up.

Second, having no exhaust vent allows you to *place one or several MUCH closer to the point of use*, for sooner hot water (convenient) without need for a very wasteful circulation system. Also, you are abandoning *much less* hot water in the pipe (economical and environmental).  **Many smaller heaters distributed near points-of-use** are a good idea if you can power them. Just look at the Brits - they build on-demand heaters right into their shower heads, for the very definition of instant hot water!

Of course, tankless water heaters take very large amounts of power for the moments they run -- but oh, look who has PowerWalls!  So on one hand, the PowerWalls, tankless heaters... sure.

### Tankless might not be fine *for you*.

Aside from the *defining* effect it has on your house's power system (the EVs aren't even rounding error compared to the tankless heaters, we'll get to that)... tankless has a fatal flaw that makes it a bad fit for you in my opinion.

First, you're gonna have solar, and you're gonna have electric cars.  Which will encourage *or even mandate* you into one of those Time-of-Use power tariffs.  A single large on-demand heater is way too much for PowerWalls, so everytime you open a faucet you're going to get mauled for 55 cents a KWH or whatever peak summer afternoon rates are.  And this defeats the purpose of the other stuff. Think about it.

**What is the purpose of a PowerWall?**

Well, the purpose is to store energy, both for blackouts and to time-shift YOUR energy so you aren't selling morning solar to the electric company for 2 cents a KWH then paying 40 cents a KWH in summer early evenings to run all your loads.

The problem is, batteries are an extremely costly way to store energy.  **A far, far, far cheaper way is thermal storage.** Consider what Alec from Technology Connections is doing:

[image]
[src](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0f9GpMWdvWI)

And this is why going tankless doesn't make sense for you.  You can use tanked heater(s) for energy storage, like Alec's house but in reverse!

Any water heater should be raised to 140F at least some of the time, to kill off dangerous bacteria.  And that means, you already need thermostatic mixing faucets (the joysticks not the 2 knobs).  Some people *overdrive* it as high as 180F to store surplus energy. Since this gets blended with more cold water, it also means longer showers before tank exhaustion.  You can also hyper-insulate the tank.

And remember what I said about multiple small tankless and faster hot water and abandoning less hot water in the pipes?  Since having lots of tank space is now desirable, that's a case for multiple tanked heaters near points of use.

### Speaking of energy storage... Pool!

Now that I've driven the point home about how *thermal* energy storage is far more cost-effective than batteries, I hope you're thinking about your pool.

Just as you might use water heaters to store solar energy that would otherwise be semi-wasted, the pool can do this *in spades and all day long*.  It is a staggeringly large energy storage.  Especially if you increase efficiency with a heat pump heater.

### All that to say...

If you want the tankless heaters, go for it.  But since your over-arcing theme is energy storage, and since you'll *probably* be on a time-of-use tariff with the power company, those tankless heaters could be a fly in the ointment.

Think it through, and if it makes sense to ditch the tankless, see if your house can get under 200A on the Load Calculation.  If there's just no hope, then press full on for the 400A. Trying to chintz out on a 300A or 350A half measure is just silly given where economies of scale have placed the pricing sweet spots.